# Importing a large csv file into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a csv file that has 310 columns and approx 4.8 million rows. 
I have tried

- LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
- sql import csv (which is basically the same thing)

I was wondering is there a better and faster method to do that.

Comment: you want to achieve this using PHP ?

Comment: if it's possible, otherwise any other method will do too.

Answer (score 0):

create a table with CSV engine , the same column to the CSV file, and copy the CSV to mysql data path, I think this is the fastest way. see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/csv-storage-engine.html

Answer (score 0):

Add **mysql** to your **PATH** environment variable and after that you can import your csv file using command line

```
mysql  -u <MYSQL_USER>  -p <MYSQL_PASSWORD>  <YOUR_DATABASENAME> < <PATH_TO_YOUR_CSV_FILE>
```